# Too many connections when downloading files using FtpWebRequest?, help me

Tags: ftpwebrequest

I use FtpWebRequest to download multiple files from the server.but when use reqFTP.Credentials to send request, it creates too many connections.how to open a connection and file down a lot, this is my code:

```
    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create (Uri));
                        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (ftpUserID,  ftpPassword);
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) reqFTP.GetResponse ();
```

each file must reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (ftpUserID, ftpPassword) once, several thousand files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN documentation about FtpWebRequest is very confusing, because they say one should reuse a FTP connection, but they don't say how. The reason why they don't say how is because you don't need to do anything special. You just create the next FtpWebRequest, which will realise that these are the same credentials and use the same connection, as long the IsKeepAlive flag is set in FtpWebRequest, which is the case by default.

The short answer is: You don't need to do anything special to reuse the ftp connection.

But you can improve your code a bit by not creating new credentials but only creating them once and then reuse them for every FtpWebRequest.